# Google Spreadsheet doesn't connect w/ python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I know this has been asked a million times, but my error hasn't seen a fix (yet I guess)

This is my code:

```
  import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = {'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/', 'https://docs.google.com/feeds'}

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('sheetjson.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open('mcresolve').sheet

print(wks.cell(1, 2))
```

I'm trying to get python to search in the file for a username, and output 2 other columns.

My error:

```
 raise APIError(response)
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

also, when I try changing my scope it doesn't work at all. So I'd rather keep using these scopes.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/513)?

Comment: like I said, the fix is updating the scope, but when I try changing my sope for some reason I get different errors.